# What bytes to emit for an ARM equivalent of EBFE?

Tags: arm

In x86, if you want to cause an infinite loop, you can emit an [ebfe](http://ebfe.org/), basically a jump to the current instruction. What's the ARM equivalent of an EBFE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be `0xeafffffe` -- an unconditional branch to itself