# What bytes to emit for an ARM64 equivalent of EBFE?

Tags: x86, arm, arm64

What is the EBFE which is for x86 equivalent for ARM64?

Saw a similar posting ([What bytes to emit for an ARM equivalent of EBFE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595940/what-bytes-to-emit-for-an-arm-equivalent-of-ebfe)) but it is not working. Probably for 32 bit>

Answer (score 2):

Since I neither *know* the exact answer, nor feel like digging out the ARMv8 ARM and hand-encoding an instruction, I'm going to cheat:

```
$ echo "b ." | aarch64-linux-gnu-as
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   14000000        b       0 <.text>
```

Well, that was easy; `0x14000000` it is.

Edit: just in case the obvious needs stating, that's the 32-bit instruction word. The actual bytes of it need to be in the correct order for the system endianness, i.e. reversed for a LE system.

Answer (score 0):

@Notlikethat 's answer is correct. Correct byte sequence is `14000000`. I am here to explain **details** with proper working code.

Let's write a simple infinite loop in **C** and compile it with *optimization level 2*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

After compilation we can now use `objdump` to analyze binary's main function:

```
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d branchitself

<snipped for brevity>

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000600 <main>:
 600:   14000000        b       600 <main>

<snipped for brevity>
```

We also can write a proper aarch64 assembly code to make single instruction to branch itself:

```
    .arch armv8-a

    .section .text
    .global _start

_start:
    b   .           // unconditional branch to itself
```

Now we can assemble, link and run the binary:

```
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-as branchitself.s -o branchitself.o
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-ld branchitself.o -o branchitself
$ qemu-aarch64 ./branchitself
```

And again let's analyze with objdump:

```
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d branchitself

branchitself:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400078 <_start>:
  400078:       14000000        b       400078 <_start>
```

I have a gist about this. You also can check that out : [Unconditional Branch/Jump to Itself](https://gist.github.com/blue-devil/9a34653d759a6dfa11acd0f88246e77b)